# Need to Solve the error: The property 'docs' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, stream, flutter-dependencies, stream-builder

Im new to flutter and faced this error i know not why.. I tried extracting the StreamBuilder widget out of the chat_screen class and giving it a separate space but that also didn't work. I have tried all the annotation suggestions it gives like putting an '!' or '?' before the snapshot.data.docs but it only recognizes till snapshot.data,  even though it does give suggestions of docs command but after the ending ';' it throws this error. I have been struggling with this since yesterday please help..

```
class MessageBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessageBuilder({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data.docs!) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        } else {
          List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>> messages = snapshot.data.docs;
          List<Text> messageWidgets = [
            Text('hello'),
          ];
          if (messages == null) {
            for (var message in messages) {
              final messageText = message.data['text'];
              final messageSender = message.data['sender'];

              final messageWidget = Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
              messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
            }
            return Column(
              children: messageWidgets,
            );
          }
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I have  initialized the line `final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;` globally.
Here is the screenshot of the error im getting.[It suggests the "docs" command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK3rC.png)   [but as soon as i use it..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veuO4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
class MessageBuilder extends StatelessWidget {
  const MessageBuilder({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      //  stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Something went wrong');
        } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text('No data available.');
        }
        List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>>? messages = snapshot.data!.docs;
        List<Text> messageWidgets = [
          Text('hello'),
        ];
        if (messages != null) {
          for (var message in messages) {
            final messageText = message.data!['text'];
            final messageSender = message.data!['sender'];

            final messageWidget = Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
            messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
          }
        }
        return Column(
          children: messageWidgets,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Using `if (snapshot.data.docs!)` seems incorrect as both data and docs could be null.

Also, why are you checking `if (messages == null)` then accessing `messages`?

Comment: Hey, Thank  you for fixing that error, however, I'm still getting the below errors in 2 lines after the "for (var message in messages) ". 
Error: "error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'."
also, i forgot to remove (messages == null) before taking the screenshot..

Comment: @KevinGomes Check the edited version, also I'm not sure if the `!` is needed in `message.data!['text']`

Comment: That error is fixed now brother, but theres this problem im facing, **Error: error: The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type. " I returned a blank text widget after all if-else blocks to get rid of it but when code runs, thats all i see.. 
Removing it brings me back to above **Error.

Comment: Check the updated code, I added a statement to check if there is an error and removed the last unnecessary `else` block since if the previous conditions were right the `return` would end the `build` function. @KevinGomes

Comment: [https://pasteboard.co/c0D4BqQmzJYI.png ]
if thats gone, then these give error..

Comment: This error is outside the scope of this question, the error in the question is fixed now, it's due to the List data type which you set as `Object?` what's the response type that you expect to get in that list? Check the documentation of the firebase. Myabe setting it like this solves it `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String,dynamic>?>>? messages = snapshot.data!.docs;` fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `snapshot.data` can be a null value, add a `?` like `snapshot.data?.docs` if you want to use it, this is my demo code:

```
          List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>>? messages = snapshot.data?.docs;
          List<Text> messageWidgets = [
            Text('hello'),
          ];
          if (messages == null) {
            for (var message in messages ?? []) {
              final messageText = message.data['text'];
              final messageSender = message.data['sender'];

              final messageWidget = Text('$messageText from $messageSender');
              messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
            }
            return Column(
              children: messageWidgets,
            );
          }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing the above error. However, after pasting this code. i get the Error: error: The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type.
I removed this error by returning a blank Text widget after all the if-else blocks(outside of all if-else) .. But after running.. That is all it returns..